# Issue while reading a parquet using pyspark : Illegal Parquet type: INT64 (TIME(MICROS,false))

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I am trying a read a set parquet files using pyspark in databricks. I am able to read few files correctly while I was getting issue in few files. So I tried to read these files in IDE and got this issue. Please let me know what this issue means and how to resolve this?

```
24/02/27 13:39:54 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)/ 1]
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Illegal Parquet type: INT64 (TIME(MICROS,false)).
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryCompilationErrors$.illegalParquetTypeError(QueryCompilationErrors.scala:1762)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetToSparkSchemaConverter.illegalType$1(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetToSparkSchemaConverter.$anonfun$convertPrimitiveField$2(ParquetSchemaConverter.scala:283)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
```

Comment: Are you reading it with the `inferSchema` set to `true`? If it is set to `false` do try out using the timestamp format option in your `spark.read` command as so - (`spark.read.option("timestampFormat", "<valid_timestamp_format>")`) e.g. of a format (`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`)